# How to check if a file is an shared library using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, operating-system

I have files like `a.so`, `lib_x.so.1`, `lib_xy.c.12`, etc, we know they're c compiled binaries.

But how to check whether the same (`is_shared_library ?`) using python program ?

Comment: What do you considered a shared library?

Comment: c compiled binaries with `.so` extension mostly.

Comment: `find / -type f -name '*.so'`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want these files communicate with each other, right?

If you 'import a' within file b or c, it'll works I think.

And if I didn't get your question the link below can provide you a solution.
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).